# What does Array((1L, 2L)) do?

Tags: scala

What does the following code do?

```
var pair: RDD[(Long,Long)] = sparkContext.parallelize(Array((3L, 4L)))
```

Does variable "pair" consist of a single element/pair? The types of 3 and 4 is "long" not "int".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It creates an `Array[Tuple2[Long,Long]]` with one element `(3L, 4L)` (aka `Tuple2(3L,4L)`).

Such case could be written (maybe more readable), as `Array(3L -> 4L)`.

> Also note it's better not to use mutable type like `Array` (rather `Seq` or `List`).

Comment: This is missing that then the Array is passed to the `parallelize` method, which creates and **RDD** of the same type of the collection. Thus and **RDD** of **Tuples** of **Long, Long**. - Additionally, it is worth mentioning that the use of **Array** is not that bad, since it is just used to call that method _(however I agree that I would have used **List** instead)_. But the fact that the final result is stored in a `var`, that is a real problem a mutable reference to an **RDD** is really a recipe for chaos.

Answer (score 0):

Let's decompose it:

- `Array(el1, el2, el3, ...)` creates a new `Array` containing the given elements. In our case, there is a single element in the array: `(3L,4L)`.
- Writing `(a,b)` creates a `Tuple2` value containing `a` and `b` of types `A` and `B` (not necessarily the same types). The `Tuple2[A,B]` type can also be written as `(A,B)` for clarity.
- In our case, `a=3L` and `b=4L`. You might be confused by the `L` suffix after literals. It is there so that the compiler can differentiate between `3` as an `Int` and `3L` as a `Long`. Scala also supports other such suffixes, like `f` or `d` for explicitly declaring `Float` or `Double` literals.

So you're indeed creating an `Array[Tuple2[Long,Long]]`, also expressed as `Array[(Long,Long)]`, which goes into your `RDD`.